# Popular for the last week and today on youtube

Tags: youtube

In the iPad YouTube application there is a list of most viewed videos for the last week and for today.

Is it possible to get the same list on the YouTube web interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Most viewed today](http://www.youtube.com/channel/HCQIQ5kK8hFJY) and [Charts](http://www.youtube.com/charts/videos_views?t=w). That should be all you need to know.

Comment: How did you get there using UI?

Comment: Cannot find a link that would lead from the main http://youtube.com to Charts. PS: in charts there are less videos than it's available in ipad app; sad, but better than nothing

Comment: Google is how I found it.